# System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm following this Xamarin Forms [quick start guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms-multiscreen/quickstart/) (the one for multiscreen)

BUT I get this error when I try to run the completed program

> **System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage**

There is no option to add a 'NavigationPage' to the shared library project.

Any ideas?  I'm using Visual Studio 15.5.2 and latest version of everything including Windows 10.

**NOTE**: in this guide the step 4 no longer matches with Visual studio
[image]

There is no longer  Cross-Platform > Forms Xaml Page, instead it has been replaced with these options

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Application` subclass (normally in the `App.cs` or `App.xaml.cs` file if created by template), wrap your first page within a NavigationPage page and now you will be able to push and pop pages.

Sample:

```
MainPage = new YourFirstPage();
```

Wrap it in a `NavigationPage`

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourFirstPage());
```

Comment: @erotavlas no problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Their nothing to do with versions, I think you miss some basics of navigations...

You have to have Navigation at first like this in App.cs

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyContentPage());
```