# PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm doing a Master Detail Page as a menu and I'm getting this error:

> PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.

When I try to instantiate another page. I believe my code already creates a navigation page when instantiate the page, but I'm not sure. Can someone help me?

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static public MasterDetailPage MasterDetail { get; set; }

    public async static Task NavigateMasterDetail(Page page)
    {
        App.MasterDetail.IsPresented = false;
        await App.MasterDetail.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
    }


    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new selectPage();
    }
```

Page that carry the menu, selectPage:

```
public partial class selectPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public selectPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Master = new Master();
        this.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Detail());

        App.MasterDetail = this;
    }
}
```

Master.xaml.cs:

```
public Master ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    toDivPage.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        await App.NavigateMasterDetail(new MainPage());
    };

    toBiqPage.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        await App.NavigateMasterDetail(new MainPage());
    };
}
```

Detail.xaml.cs is empty.

Comment: Actually, I'm new on Xamarin and I don't know exactly what I did wrong, so I need help to figure out what I did so this error appear...

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621814/pushasync-is-not-supported-globally-on-android-please-use-a-navigationpage-xa or https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18590/how-to-work-around-pushasync-is-not-supported-globally-on-android or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070606/system-invalidoperationexception-pushasync-is-not-supported-globally-on-android help?

Comment: It doesn't... Already accessed these links before posting :/  Actually, I was following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBqdI77_p-M tutorial and for him work perfectly and mine didn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you have to use `NavigationPage` in your `App.xaml.cs`.
In your `App.xaml.cs` make sure your constructor or `App` method looks like this

```
public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new selectPage());
    }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I tried to do this, but it just added one more blue bar and the error persists... https://i.imgur.com/krH2D2a.jpg (the error happens when I open the menu and click in the button that should call another page)

Comment: Since you have NavigationPage in your `App.xaml.cs`, you can use `Navigation.PushAsync(new Page());` for other navigations in the app

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would be the exactly implementation of that? Like this? https://i.imgur.com/B2BYd4L.png  (sorry I'm realy noob xD)

Comment: Yes. Did that fix the issues for you?

Comment: Actually, with the " MainPage = new NavigationPage(new selectPage());" it works for me, but then things will be like this: https://i.imgur.com/F9RQcES.jpg with 2 blue bars...

Comment: oh. We are almost there. You just have to remove the extra Navigation bar. Use `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar = "false";` in your `xaml`

Comment: Yaaaaay, it works perfectly! Thanks haha (for the patience)

Comment: Yay! Awesome :)